# How to use an external jQuery plugin with Drupal's no-conflict jQuery

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm using drupal_add_js() to load some external js:

```
drupal_add_js('http://jquery-accordion.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.accordion.js', 'external');
```

This produces 'TypeError: $ is not a function' errors because Drupal uses jQuery in no-conflict mode.

So I think the only solution is to copy the code, wrap it in this function and call it locally:

```
(function ($) {
  // Original JavaScript code.
})(jQuery);
```

I wondered whether there was a trick to still be able to directly use external js?

Comment: Tried JQuery Update? You will be able to use a google-hosted jquery which I believe is correct one for your case. May be the counterpart - modifying the new js file?

Comment: I've been avoiding JQuery Update because I think it breaks some things (Panels), but will give it a try.

Comment: I don't have any problems with jQuery Update and Panels.

Comment: To be honest, the best option it to patch the external script, and send it to the author.  jQuery best practice is to write the plugin so that it will work in no-conflict environments.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, if you a certain that the external scripts are attempting to use "$" as an alias for jQuery, and you can't get the script author to patch their code, and you aren't loading any other JavaScript libraries, then in your template_preprocess_page, place the following drupal_add_js before the set of all drupal_add_js that reference external files. All scripts in the header region that use "$" as an alias will then refer to jQuery:

```
drupal_add_js('var $ = jQuery;', 'inline');
```

If your external javascript is added in another region, for example, the footer, then use something similar to the following instead:

```
drupal_add_js('var $ = jQuery;', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));
```